# .htaccess - “Too many redirects”

Tags: .htaccess

Установил SSL сертификат и началась проблема с редиректом. Если в htaccess ничего не указывать, то сайт работает и с https и без. Заходит и так и так, но у меня не получается редиректнуть с http://spteh.com.ua/ на https://spteh.com.ua/ что бы всегда заходило только на https.

```css
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В таком варианте работают обе линки, а если добавить

```css
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} spteh.com.ua
RewriteRule (.*) https://spteh.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ (/[^?]*)(\?([^\ ]*))?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .? - [E=method:%1,E=myURI:%2,E=curURI:%2,E=myQS:%4,E=curQS:%4]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule .? - [E=myHOST:%1]
```

начинает редиректить на https://spteh.com.ua но выдает ошибку Too many redirects Где, я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

У вас вот эта часть:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} spteh.com.ua
RewriteRule (.*) https://spteh.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

всегда имеет значение "Истина".

Поскольку вы проверяете `HTTP_HOST` на равенство имени домена `spteh.com.ua`, и редирект происходит на этот же домен, то в этом месте происходит зацикливание, приводящее к результату `Too many redirects`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение

```css
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```